# Deleting rows in Excel table through SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to delete all rows that match entries in an array. Right now I'm trying to put values from an array to a string, which I know won't work, but I'm having trouble figuring out the right method. Any suggestions? (or should I not be using SQL to do this?)

```vb
Public Sub DeleteRows(ByVal surveyString As String)

    Dim surveyArr() As String
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL as String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strCon As String

    strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cn.Open strCon

    If surveyString <> "" Then
        surveyArr = Split(surveyString, "|")
    End If

    'this is where I need help
    strSQL = "DELETE * FROM [Employee$] AS e WHERE e.Division IN " & surveyArr
    rs.Open strSQL, cn
```

Comment: I don't think you can delete rows using ADO against an Excel file.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. I've got around 15 columns and 800k rows. Is looping through each cell in a column to determine if I need to delete it a good idea?

Comment: Have you considered using an actual database?

Comment: Would love to, but in my current situation that's not possible

Comment: Not a good idea to loop through each cell, but you can load your data to an array  `arr = range(yourrange)` and loop through it there, the delete the rows you want using the index of the array matching your criteria.

Comment: Could you just select the results you want to keep, and push that data someplace else? E.g. `Select * from [Employee$] AS e WHERE e.Division NOT IN ...`

Comment: 'you cannot:...Delete an entire record at once or you receive the following error message: "Deleting data in a linked table is not supported by this ISAM." You can only delete a record by blanking out the contents of each individual field...You cannot delete the empty spreadsheet row(s) in which the deleted data was located, and your recordset will continue to display empty records corresponding to these empty rows.' from [this old MSDN article](http://web.archive.org/web/20120102174324/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819)